# In TSQL, How do I add a count column that counts the number of rows in my query?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, aggregate-functions, rows

This can be done a number of ways, which I will explain at the end. For now, I have been given a work assignment that includes the following (simplified):

"Create a record each week to track the current status that has the following: account numbers (unique within each report), a random number (provided), their status (Green, Orange, or Blue), and make sure the record also has a column which tells me how many records their are this week."

I do *not* need code to generate a random number.

Columns: Account, RanNum, Status, NumberOfRowsThisWeek

How do I handle adding a column that determines the number of rows in my query and produces that number, static, within each row of that column?

I may try to tweak the request and apply a rising number. How would I go about doing it in this case?

Edit: SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not telling us which database you are using.

In SQL Server, the newer versions at least, you have windowing function or analytical functions available, and they are also available in most other popular RDBMS

You could do what you want in SQL Server by adding this to your select

```
,count(*) over (partition by 1) as [NrOfRows]
```

An analytical function does the "standard" query, and then performs the windowing function on the result set. 
The count above, counts the rows in the result set, partitioned by the constant 1, which is of course stable across all rows, so it gives the full rowcount.

It is perhaps not standard in all databases to allow a constant in that way, perhaps this would give a better result in some, I know it works in SQL Server:

```
,count(*) over (partition by (select 1 n)) as [NrOfRows]
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try! 
It is SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you want to do some kind of simple count() / group by query

```
select Account, RanNum, Status, count(*) as NumberOfRowsThisWeek
from tablename
group by Account, RanNum, Status
```

you my need to do

```
select Account, RanNum, Status, NumberOfRowsThisWeek
from (
   select Account, Status, count(*) as NumberOfRowsThisWeek
   from tablename
   group by Account, Status
)
```

because the random number will confuse the group by by making every row unique.